# wrapBootstrap is no updated and what about copyrights

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My questions are:

- Is wrapBootstrap site (for buying themes) no updated?
  I'm watching the statics of subscribers and of buyers a couple of days and none has been increased.  Is it safe to buy a bootstrap theme from there?
- And what about the copyrights of the buying themes?
  On my footer I must notice that designer is: "e.g. Company blah blah" or I can only write that I'm the delevoper of the site and nothing about the design?

Answer (score 2):

The Site is reliable and I have some themes there. I got timely payment. The only problem is the support. 0 support. No response for more than 10 emails I sent. If they increase the support than that Site will be a great place to buy and sell themes.

As for the copyright you are free to change the footer link. No problem.

Comment: thanks you for your reply.  I had send the same Question on their   support e-mail (twice) but no respond.. yy, their support is awful. xD

Comment: @Badu (http://stackoverflow.com/users/1713206/babu) to buy  a theme I must to lsign up on wrapbootstrap? or i can buy and without sign in?

Comment: First sign up with the site. Because if you got any problems then you can contact the author.

Comment: If there is any problem with the theme then better contact the theme author.

Comment: You are very correct. They are not rsponding for any support emails and My payment is keeps on delaying.